# Regular expression fixed digit size in my expression

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, regex, visual-studio

I have a expression that I want to add another function to it.

Now I can type 
0736544565 10 digits 
And
+46736589787 11 digit with a + at the beginning.

In the expression you have to begin with 07 or +467 an then any digit. I want to fix the size to but I have problem to put the condition in the expression. 
When it starts with 07 I want to limit it/fix size on the digit to 10 digits
when it starts with +467 I want to limit it/fix size on the digit to 12 digit or 11 without the +

My expression: `ValidationExpression="^(07).+|(\+?467).+">`

How do I put this condition in the expression?

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
ValidationExpression="^(07|\+?467)\d{8}$"
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using a regex like:

```
^07\d{8}\b|^\+?467\d{8}\b
```

Essentially 8 digit following the prefix you had mentioned.